# How to call a function with a different class as parameter

Tags: python

So, this is probably a really simple question but I just cant figure it out:

I have 1 function that, when called, uses the variables from a class to return either a True or False:

```
def adjacente(dist):
     return(
          abs(totalmov.xi - totalmov.xf) == dist and abs(totalmov.yi - totalmov.yf) <= dist or
          abs(totalmov.yi - totalmov.yf) == dist and abs(totalmov.xi - totalmov.xf) <= dist)
```

But the thing is, I want to be able to execute this function without having it hardcoded to the class "totalmov", for instance, I want to be able to execute the same very function with the class "movimento" and the only way I have thought so far was to create the same very function but with a different name:

```
def adjacente_2(dist):
    return(
        abs(movimento.xi - movimento.xf) == dist and abs(movimento.yi - movimento.yf) <= dist or
        abs(movimento.yi - movimento.yf) == dist and abs(movimento.xi - movimento.xf) <= dist)
```

There 100% must be a way to do the same thing but without repeating functions, can someone tell me how? Thank you

Comment: Should we assume that a) the classes cannot be altered, and/or b) the two classes are not related, and thus it wouldn't make sense to have them both inherit from a common parent? The easiest solution would be to apply inheritance, but that may not be appropriate.

Comment: i'll look into inheritance to see if it applies to what i am trying to do, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is add another parameter to your function definition (called something sensible; here, I've called it `movement`), and then use that in place of the class names inside your function body:

```py
def adjacente(dist, movement):
     return(
          abs(movement.xi - movement.xf) == dist and abs(movement.yi - movement.yf) <= dist or
          abs(movement.yi - movement.yf) == dist and abs(movement.xi - movement.xf) <= dist)
```

So long as whatever you pass as a function argument has attributes of appropriate types called `xi`, `yi`, `xf`, and `yf`, this will work.